# KendoUI Grid - Line disappears when canceling editing

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I have a grid, without ajax transport. I just use put item directly in the MVVM. I can create and edit lines into it. But wen I edit a line that I've just created and then I cancel the edition, the line is deleted.

An example says more than a thousand words : http://dojo.telerik.com/oREqi/2

Is this behaviour normal? I don't think so...
What's the cure?

Comment: Probably feature, not bug, I would guess that when you click cancel, it re-reads the `dataSource` to avoid having to create a temporary copy of the item's information. In the real world, changes would be written to database after you add new record, so upon re-reading the `dataSource` the item would persist. Again, this is a guess.

Comment: I'm wrong, post on Telerik's forums.